# Разложение числа на элементы

Tags: delphi

Помогите разложить число (например 8,3) на такие составляющие: целые 5-ки: одна, и остаток 3,3. Нужно их присвоить разным переменным.  Ещё пример: 16,7: это будет 3-и пятёрки и 1,7. Нужно, чтобы получились две переменных:

```
perem1:='3';  
perem2:='1,7';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Var
  Value, Perem2: Extended;
  Perem1: Integer;
Begin
  Value:=16.7;
  Perem1:=Trunc(Value) Div 5;
  Perem2:=Value-Perem1*5;
End;
```